# Adding http/https check to regular expression

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

Possibly an easy solution to this one, but I am new to regular expressions. Apologies if posted in the wrong area etc. newbie with posting to stackoverflow too!

I am try to add a check to the following code to make sure the entered string (URL in this case) contains http:// or https:// at the beginning, hope you can help!

`(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$`

Comment: So what does that Regex do?

Comment: At the moment it is checking that the rest of the URL address is correctly formatted, and putting limits on the amount of characters used, but is not checking that the address contains http:// or http:// at the beginning which I specifically need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^http(s|)://[^ ]+$
```

This will check if your url starts with `http` or `https` and not contain any spaces on it.

EDITED:

ok so I see that what you really want is a url validation regex, try this one:

```
(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[a-z ;,./?%&=]*)?
```

Comment: I've added this, it is almost right but now my code is counting addresses like this as being correct: http://.google.com OR http://!google.com - ^http(s|)://[^ ]?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$

Comment: Thank You Victor, this has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this regex

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

This will work for both http and https.